# Who is paying for a transaction within a contract?

Tags: truffle, gas, evm, gas-price

Let's assume I do a transaction to a contract function with my external account, then I have to pay gas for this transaction.

If the function within the contracts makes now a transaction on his own to write something to an other contracts, who is paying then for this?

I was testing this in my `truffle develop` environment and it looks like my account just paid for the transaction to the first contract, not for the second transaction.

I also didn't send any Ether to the first contracts before. But the second transaction worked as well.

- Are transaction from contracts free?
- Or is this just a special behaviour in my test environment to make thing easier?

---

edit:

The contract makes a simple transaction, something like this:

```
contract First {
    Second secondContract;
    uint test;

    function setSomething(uint _testValue) external {
        secondContract.set(_testValue); //also set a uint within contract 2
        test = _testValue;
    }
}
```

If I add the following line in my test, the result is 0 Ether because I never send Ether to this contract.

```
console.log(`Contract balance: ${web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(firstContact.address))}`);
```

The test still works and if i read the value from the second contract I also get the right value back.

Comment: do you maybe have some code as an example? When you fire a transaction from within a contract it is paid for by the contract itself. Transactions are never free.

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: The gas used by the contract is calculated in on the initial to First call in this case!

Comment: Ok, just to make it clear: If I call this first contract, I pay also with my account for the second transaction within the first contract?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens

Comment: Thanks, thats exaclty what I wanted to know. Maybe one additional question. Can I compare my results on my testnet with the mainnet? Lets say a transaction cost 0.001 Ether on my testnet...will it be the same on the mainnet?

Comment: ...for exactly the same contract.

Comment: Yes, there are fixed gas costs for certain op-codes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gas consumed by your transaction is the total gas used during the execution of your call to `Contract A`. If A makes a call (or delegatecall) to another contract, the gas consumed by that is also added to the gas consumed by your transaction.

If you look at the [Parity trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x85fb4eced3537ff40deb5e73057df7c2cb94f5a97f9e0dbb16e328980889e482&type=parity) for one such transaction, you can see the various other contracts invoked, and how much gas the invocation used. The final cost of the transaction includes all of this.